# C++ this and constant object

Tags: c++, this, constants, callable-object

could you tell me why this code works? There is overloaded operator() which is used by `replace_if` algorithm. In main function I've created constant object of IsEqual class so only constant function member should be used. Somehow constancy isn't working and that operator is called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class IsEqual {
    int value;
public:
    IsEqual(int v) : value(v) {}
    bool operator()(const int &elem){
    this->value=6;
    return elem == value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const IsEqual tst(2);
    std::vector<int> vec = {3,2,1,4,3,7,8,6};
    std::replace_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), tst, 5);
    for (int i : vec) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

result: 3 2 1 4 3 7 8 5

Comment: Look at the signature of [`replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) and consider how the predicate argument is declared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::replace_if` will make its own copy of the `tst` object. It is not required to restrict it to be `const`.

If you want to use the original object in the algorithm, you can use an `std::reference_wrapper`. Since it would be referring to a `const` object,this would result in a compiler error because it would require the operator to be `const`:

```
std::replace_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ref(tst), 5);
```